# Consecutively measuring $\hat{s_x}^2$, $\hat{s_y}^2$ and $\hat{s_z}^2$ of a spin 1 particle, results in what?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I am hearing a [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hox6ZIj7JPI) from John Conway on the [free will theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_will_theorem). This is more or less a purely mathematical theorem (with physical consequences). But it is so since Conway and Kochen deliberately separated the Physics by putting it into the assumptions. These are their three axioms: TWIN, SPIN, FIN. In my understanding they are a necessary consequence of current Physics. Now I'd like to see that myself for SPIN. It states

> The squared spin component of certain elementary particles of spin one, taken in three orthogonal directions, will be a permutation of (1,1,0).

(What is meant here is surely a consecutive measurement of the three components on one particle).

Is there a way to directly calculate this, using e.g. commutation relations between $\hat{s_\alpha}^2$ and $\hat{s_\beta}^2$ for $\alpha, \beta \in$ {x,y,z} and $\alpha\neq\beta$.

My vague idea about the reason for that is, that in case two perpendicular measurements would give 0 the third would be determined, which is not possible due to the non-commutativity of the spin-components. All three 1s (1,1,1) and all three 0s (0,0,0) would contradict the total spin which we set to 1. So only one possibility is left. But I do not know how to put that into a formally correct argument (if it is correct at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Caution: I don't know QM well, so I barely know what I'm talking about)

It is interesting that $S_x^2$, $S_y^2$ and $S_z^2$ commute for spin-1 particle. You can check it e.g. by inspection using their matrix representations. So your proof seems to be incorrect for me.

The idea behind the SPIN axiom I think is the next: eigenvalues of $S_i^2$ are 0 and 1, and they should add up to 2 because eigenvalue of $S^2=S_x^2+S_y^2+S_z^2$ is $s(s+1) = 2$.

Comment: Oh dear, that simple (after the surprise of commutation)!